# How to check a list of string values in a condition statement

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to check the value of a list of string in a condition, with out creating a for each or counter loop.

**For Example**

```
string extention = Path.GetExtension(attachment.Name).ToLower();

List<string> validExtentions = new List<string>() { ".tif", ".tiff", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jif", ".png", ".pdf", ".txt", ".jpg" };

if(extention.Contains(validExtentions))
{

}
```

I thought I could use a `.contains` function which is expecting a string not a list of string so it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to flip your variables. You checking if your `extension` is contained inside the list of `validExtensions`:

```
if(validExtensions.Contains(extension))
{

}
```

Comment: Should you account for variable casing?  Maybe `validExtentions.Contains(extention, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`?

Comment: @roryap - Probably, but the OP doesn't mention that they need to worry about case. If they do, it's a trivial matter of using an overload of `Contains`.

Comment: I am lowering the case in string extention = Path.GetExtension(attachment.Name).ToLower();

Comment: @EasyE -- That's fine for small examples, but that type of string manipulation, given that strings are immutable, is not recommended.  I would recommend using case-invariant options when comparing strings like the overload in my first comment and forget converting to lowercase.  Just a note for the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about this....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace EasyE
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test strings
        List<extention> extentions = new List<extention>() { 
            new extention { FileName = "File1.jif" }, 
            new extention() { FileName = "File2.TIFF" },
            new extention() { FileName = "File3.txt" } };
        ///////////////

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*\.(tif|tiff|gif|jpeg|jif)$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if ((from ext in extentions where (ext.FileName.ToString() == regex.Match(ext.FileName.ToString()).Value) select ext).Count() > 0)
        {

        }
    }
}

class extention
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
}
```